# White space to the right when the browser is resized

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble how to fix the white space on the right side of this website.
Please, can someone help me? Here is a screenshot.

[image]

and here is the site http://ottserby.lr-dev.com/ TIA

Comment: Have you fixed it? It displays fine for me in chrome.

Comment: Seems it has been fixed..

Comment: nope,  Im using chrome too, the white space is still there, as you can see in the screenshot. Resize it to a smaller window you can see the white gap on the right

Comment: There seems to be a 10px solid #fff border on the div#feature_list that is wider than the other content.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the code that you apply style in your site for the header menu.I increased the width size so that it appears as a better when you resize.

```
.top-container-inner .header-menu {
    background: transparent url("/static/images/desktop/menu-bar.gif") repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    position: static;
    height: 61px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width:1189px;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

> Actually the image used for the menu-bar is the problem if you remove the menu-bar image it look like this as a correct one.here is a link of that image[image: on removing the background]
>
> The main thing is that a proper website means there is no scroll bar on the bottom which makes you to design your site proper for all type of screens.so keep doing